# jquery plugin for international phone number validations

Tags: jquery, validation, phone-number

Can you guys suggest a good telephone number validation plugin for jQuery for both US and International numbers? I Googled a lot but could not find a one that worked well.

It would be great if there was a live validation (i.e.: it validates instantly when the user types the phone number in the input field)

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest using [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and then extended the functionality by using the code below, which I found on [this blog post](http://www.24hourapps.com/2009/02/jquery-international-phone-number.html).

It offers a nice snippet of code (and it gets better in the comments) which you can use for international numbers as well as US phone numbers. I was already using the `additional methods` plugin so I renamed the method `intlphone`, and then the code to my web page, after jQuery and before the `document.ready` / validation setup:

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod('intlphone', function(value) { return (value.match(/^((\+)?[1-9]{1,2})?([-\s\.])?((\(\d{1,4}\))|\d{1,4})(([-\s\.])?[0-9]{1,12}){1,2}(\s*(ext|x)\s*\.?:?\s*([0-9]+))?$/)); }, 'Please enter a valid phone number');
```

On the input field I wanted to be a phone number I set the class to be `intlphone` and added an HTML5 property / attribute for minimum length (although this could also be done by specifying the validation rules when setting up validation), so my input was something like:

```
<input class="required intlphone" name="phone" minLength="7" type="text" />
```

As the blog post says it accepts digits as well as `-+()` and also spaces and extensions in the format `x:` or `ext:`

It's not a guarantee that a phone number will be valid 100% of the time but it's not a bad start.

Answer (score 3):

What is the only thing really(!) valid about a phone number? At least internationally speaking, there is no such thing as a general format for phone numbers. You can write only digits, use some parentheses, dashes, plus signs etc. But what really matters are the digits. There is not even a common length restriction in most countries.

So no, I've not seen a usable phone number validator yet.

Comment: +1, validating both us and international numbers will be impossible.

Comment: Actually there is a way, you can validate a number that accomplish https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164